# How to get server time using javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am  changing my question What is missing or wrong in this code When user type something in the `textboxt`  onother `texbox` supposed to get  server time But nothing happens.I am so inexperience with programming.Can you plase help

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Response.Expires = -1;
      Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
      Response.End();
}

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function ajaxFunction() {
    var xmlHttp;

        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {


                document.getElementById("user").value = xmlHttp.responseText;

            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = "wait";

            }


            xmlHttp.open("GET", "Default.aspx", true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);

        }
}

 </script>
<title></title>
</head>
 <body>
   <input id="user" type="text"  onkeyup="ajaxFunction()"/>
  <p>
    <input id="time" type="text" /></p>
<div id="label">
</div>
<p>
    &nbsp;</p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misplaced the call to actually start the request

```
function ajaxFunction() {
    var xmlHttp;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById("user").value = xmlHttp.responseText;
        } // closes the if
        else {
            document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = "wait";
        } // closes the else
    } // closes the function() for onreadystatechange
    // call the stuff
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "Default.aspx", true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```